# How to perform Hardware disaster recovery with backup server

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2012, hardware, disaster-recovery

I have a two windows server 2003 R2 servers with same configuration(same processor,same motherboard etc). One is original server and another one is backup server(Not to store backup files,it is a server used in case original server gets crashed). So in case any hardware problem in original server like motherboard problem then I remove all the hard disk from original server(Including drive containing OS) and connect it to backup server. So I will have low down time. The configuration was same OS was also working properly after changing drive having Windows OS.

Now we have plan to purchase new server with windows server 2012 and we will be purchasing Intel 2600 family processor and supporting motherboard as original server. For backup server I will be purchasing Intel 2400 family processor and its supported motherboard. So in case of any problem in original server Does shifting hard disk(like I was doing before) will work?(In ordinary windows 7 pc it was not working when hardware changes are there) . If it does not work then what is the solution? How this kind of hardware errors are handled by using backup server or any other methods to do the same.
Is there any procedures to take backup of existing server configurations like folder permissions, software configurations, users etc.? If yes, can i restore the backup of main server to alternate server in case of server failure?
Please suggest me on this.

We have our own backup program and we are taking backup in regular basis. Only thing we are confused about is hardware failure.

Comment: Just stop it. This is not the right way of implementing disaster recovery. Use Windows Server Backup or the backup product of your choice that can perform bare metal restores to dissimilar hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Your question could be more concise however I'll do my best to answer.

I would not count on being able to simply remove the disks from one machine and plant them into another, especially if the RAID controller is different. There are any number of factors (RAID controller, RAID level, etc) that would make this a risky operation and I would certainly not recommend it for a DR situation.

What you're looking to do can be accomplished with virtualization and shared storage. You would have your two physical servers (in this case your primary server and your secondary server) and your storage (hard drives) would be on an array separate from these two servers (ie storage array, SAN, NAS, etc).This allows for a seamless failover should the hardware on one of your two servers fail. The caveat here is that you now have all your data on a storage array, so you'd likely want two of those in case one or the other fails.

For more information (on vmware) you can look here : http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere/features-high-availability

Comment: Besides RAID definiely not working between different products you can also not count on the discs WORKING. Disaster is a wide area and can include stuff like - flooding or a fire.

Comment: Good point @TomTom - What i'm discussing does not encompass a full disaster recovery plan, but rather local, non-storage related, hardware failure. Any backup plan should also include backups of server, with at least one copy of such data being remote at all times.